# WebAPI - 403 thrown after Azure service change

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-403

We have Web API (.NET 4.6, MVC with WebAPI 5.2.3).

Once deployed on the Azure, everything works fine, flawless.
But almost every Monday when we try to access the API, 403 error is thrown.

It took us a while to find why is this happening. Apparently when something on Azure changes, regarding of service (power of the machine, number of instances) the API starts throwing 403 error.

Not even restart helps, the only thing that fixes the problem is republish of API.

So every Monday (I guess because there's a little traffic on Azure over the weekend) the service scales down and 403 error appears.

Comment: how is it hosted on Azure ? Azure VM ? azure webapp? or something else ?

Comment: It is hosted as app service @RaviA.

Comment: It's tough to troubleshoot this but any idea what is the sub status code ?

Comment: No, not really. When I call the API from the web app this is the error thrown http://imgur.com/aXavw8J.

If I try to access the API directly in browser I get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." shown. @RaviA.

Comment: looks like you are running into ACL issue (guessing based on the error message) and deploying the app service again is resetting those ACLs. What is the authentication that is set ? Also what is the application pool identity ?

Comment: User logs on Web App with his Azure AD credentials, Web API trusts the App that the user is authenticated/authorized with TrustedCallerClientId,
everything works fine until something on Azure has changed. @RaviA.

Comment: How does API authenticated when accessed directly from browser ? You get a windows login prompt ?

Comment: No, just the default API/MVC page opens up, only other controllers require authentication. The interesting thing is, that page, the main page says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" once something on Azure changes, even it doesn't require authentication. @RaviA.

Comment: Really hard to troubleshoot this one. Would recommend to open a support case with Microsoft as if this is issue with ACL it's only Microsoft that will have access to the actual server logs.

Comment: Will do it then, thank you for your effort and time @RaviA.